# Drawing lines in 3D space in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix looking like:

```
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[7 8 9]
```

I have drawn the 3 points in a 3d space using scatter 3 so that I have `A(1 2 3) B (4 5 6) C(7 8 9)`

How can I add a line going from A to B and one from B to C? I tried the line command but it didn't do what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data =  [A B C]; % combine all points together
d1 = [1:3:length(data)];    % construct the index for each dimension
d2 = [2:3:length(data)];
d3 = [3:3:length(data)];

plot3(data(d1),data(d2),data(d3));    plot the data using plot3 function
```